# hydration error in next.js when using the div tag instead of the main tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I've encountered the hydration error in nextjs and on debugging I found that when I use the div tag instead of the main tag then it causes this issue.

**The error that I get**

[image]
**Below is the code that caused the error**

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

type Props = {};

const LearnTesting = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Learn Testing</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LearnTesting;
```

**Below is the code that runs flawlessly**

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

type Props = {};

const LearnTesting = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Learn Testing</h1>
    </main>
  );
};

export default LearnTesting;
```

*You can see the only difference is the usage of the div tag instead of the main tag causing the hydration error.*

While going through the documentation I don't see an explanation related to the usage of semantic tags or anything related. It only mentions incorrect nesting of tags. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you tried Hard Reload or cleaning Cache

1. On Chrome, Press right click on reload button → Select Empty Cache and Hard Reload
2. Just go the browser, Chrome → three bars button on top right corner (hamburger menu) → more tools → Developer tools → Applocation tab → storage → clear site data
3. There can be a chance your `<LearnTesting />` Component is rendering inside h1 Like:

```
<h1>
  <LearningTesting />
</h1>
```